# What are the conditions to have ssh_config re-parsed?

Tags: ssh, configuration

When setting up an ssh_config, we make use of host-name canonicalization. Unfortunately, in some unique cases, this canonicalization is not always possible and has to be done by adding an additional section into the config file.

```
CanonicalizeHostname yes
CanonicalDomains first.domain second.domain third.domain
CanonicalizeFallbackLocal yes
CanonicalizeMaxDots 0

Match host name1
  HostName %h.first.domain
```

Additionally, as we use multiple include files. Assume that `ssh_config_main` contains the default canonicalization and various other configurations, while `ssh_config_spec` contains some specializations, of which some are "manual" canonicalizations.

```
Include ssh_config_main
Include ssh_config_spec
```

To have the configuration working as expected, it would be required that, for each change of hostname —done by Canonicalization or Match block— the full configuration is re-parsed.

**Question:** what are the conditions to have the configuration re-parsed, and can I enforce it?

**Note:** the only reference to re-parsing is a fuzzy statement in `man ssh_config` about Canonicalization being enabled or the use of the `final` keyword. Would a single line of the form `Match final` already enforce it?